# How to search Javascript Array, and return all strings in array that start with X

Tags: javascript

I was wondering what the best approach would be to search a javascript array of strings, and return all strings in that array that begin with a given string.

If anybody has any ideas, or if there is an even easier way of achieving this with JQuery please help me out!

For Example,

```
var arrayOfStrings = ["apple", "banana", "peach", "orange", "plum"];
var searchString = "p";
```

So if I search `arrayOfStrings` with `searchString` it would return `plum` and `peach`

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. Array initializer syntax uses `[]` not `{}`.

Comment: Use `.filter()`, but more importantly, read [MDN's documentation for Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Oh yeah, just typing mistake as typing question. It is correct in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var searchString = /^p/;
var result = arrayOfStrings.filter(function(str){
    return searchString.test(str)
};
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** I updated my answer as comments below pointed out, thanks to [cookie monster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3096782/cookie-monster) and [Havenard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156811/havenard)

Try [array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var re = new RegExp('^' + searchString);
var matches = arrayOfStrings.filter(re.test, re);
```

**UPDATE**

If you want it case insensitive:

```
var re = new RegExp('^' + searchString, 'i');
```

Please note that if your search string contains special characters you would need to escape them first because of the way strings work. Thanks to [Alex Pakka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216374/alex-pakka) for pointing this out.

Comment: You could actually shorten this a bit if you wanted. `arrayOfStrings.filter(re.test, re);`

Comment: Note `.filter()` don't modify the array, it creates a new one.

Comment: @Havenard It was just for the example but you are right I'll update and assign it to point this out.

Comment: This Works Great! I have another question, if the array contains strings with uppercases and lower cases, how can I test the RegExp ignoring the case, of the strings in the array?

Comment: @BobbyW yes sure, `new RegExp('^' + searchString, 'i');` will ignore the case, I updated my answer

Comment: Very nice solution - I prefer yours. Of course, you would need to escape searchString if it has regexp control chars... just wanted to point out. Also posted binary search based approach with speed numbers if anyone cares as an alternative - but you probably don't ;-)

Comment: I actually do, and thanks for pointing this out, I'll warn about it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One of solution:

```
var arrayOfStrings = ["apple", "banana", "peach", "orange", "plum"];
var searchString = "p";
var result = []
arrayOfStrings.forEach(function(entry) {
   if(entry.indexOf(searchString)==0)
   {  result.push(entry);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need short and fast, use filter() and indexOf() as the accepted answer suggested.

Here is a version geared towards **speed** and will help only if array is at least 20 elements big or larger and you need to perform lots of searches:

```
//somewhere in your initialization code, extend array prototype
Array.prototype.binaryPrefixFilter = function(find) {
  var low = 0, high = this.length - 1,
      i, el;
  while (low <= high) {
    i = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
    el = this[i];
    if (el.indexOf(find)==0) { 
        //go left and right to find elements
        var start = i, end = i;
        while (--start > 0 && this[start].indexOf(find)==0);  
        while (++end < this.length && this[end].indexOf(find)==0);
        return this.splice(start+1,end-start-1);
    }
    if (el < find) { low = i + 1; }
       else        { high = i - 1; };
  }
  return [];
}; 


//actual use, notice sort() at the end
var arrayOfStrings = ["apple", "banana", "peach", "orange", "plum"].sort();
console.log(arrayOfStrings.binaryPrefixFilter("p")); //["peach","plum"]
```

Obviously, if you are creating a library, you should not change the `Array` prototype, but this is beyond the scope of this answer.

**UPDATE:** SPEED COMPARISON

Here are the real numbers in Chrome 35 on i7 with array of 100 real world English names.

```
 10k searches with `fitler(regExp.test, regExp)` : 119ms 
 10k searches via binary search as above: 11ms
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Exceeder/CrhaX/) to play with. So, unless you are on the server side like nodeJs, it probably is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways this is one:

```
var exp1 = /^[p]/;    
var results = ["apple", "banana", "peach", "orange", "plum"].filter(
    function(item){  return exp1.test(item);  });//returns plum and peach
```

Using `Array.prototype.filter` you can filter items from an Array. And using RegEx you can use simple of complex matching expressions.

Comment: Misuse of `[]` there.

Answer (score 0):

```
function search_starting_with(haystack, needle)
{
    var result = [];
    for (var i in haystack)
        if (haystack[i].indexOf(needle) == 0)
            result[result.length] = haystack[i];
    return result;
}

var arrayOfStrings = ["apple", "banana", "peach", "orange", "plum"];
var searchString = "p";

alert(search_starting_with(arrayOfStrings, searchString));
```

This solution should do too:

```
var filteredArrayOfStrings = arrayOfStrings.filter(function (v) { return v.indexOf(searchString) == 0; });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7MZYU/

Answer (score 0):

Try using strings indexOf() method:

```
var arrayOfStrings = ["apple", "banana", "peach", "orange", "plum"];
var searchString = "p";
var results = [];
for(var i = 0;i<arrayOfStrings.length;i++){
    var temp = arrayOfStrings[i].indexOf(searchString);
    if(temp == 0)
        results.push(arrayOfStrings[i]);
}
return results;
```

Comment: why would you -1 this ?

Comment: arrayOfStrings should be in [], and according to his/her demands it should be if(temp == 0).

Comment: Oh didn't notice copied it from the question

Comment: Because it'll return false positives, like `apple`, you're using the invalid syntax that was in the question, and you have a misplaced `return` statement.

Comment: Thank you for notifying me of false positives... didn't read the question aswell as I should have...

Answer (score 0):

```
var resultArr = ["apple", "banana", "peach", "orange", "plum"].filter(function(v){ return v[0]=='p' });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joopmicroop/fA3ut/)

Comment: depending on your searchstring requirements this will work. And is still a valid answer. Read the title of the question: "How to search Javascript Array, and return all strings in array that start with X" I also used the same searchstring and array as the example given by the asker.